# Visual Studio 2010, asp.net mvc3 web.config for Debug and Release

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I want to use Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config each.

But it does not work in Visual Studio 2010 And it works on actual server after deployment.

**Web.Release.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID" value="LIVE_GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

**Web.Debug.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID" value="DEBUG_GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID" xdt:Transform="Insert" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

I have like above config files and I try to echo on screen the config value.

```
string t = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID"]; Response.Write(t);
```

On Visual studio,

[image]

set as Release mode, and F5 (also I tried Build Solution(F6)) but it doesn't print anything.

So I try to Deployment package and install on server and run then it prints the right value.

How I do for that in Visual studio? I want to make sure everything OK before deploy package.

Please advise me~

Thank you!

[Edit]

Now I get it, thank you for everyone who gave me nice answer!

May I ask one more question please?

then what's this for?

[image]

If I change to Release or Debug then what effect to my project?

Comment: You could publish to your local machines IIS in release mode, then you will see the correct web.config deployed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual studio 2010 - debug using "release" web.config transform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734612/visual-studio-2010-debug-using-release-web-config-transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734829/611288

As Jimmy says, the web.config transforms are only applied during the Web Publish Pipleline

Jimmy also supplies the following link for a hack: http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx

Alternatively, create a test deploy that deploys locally and test the config settings there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to build web.config when building your solution. You could get around this by executing an xml merge tool as a post-build event based on your selected build configuration. Something like [`XmlConfigMerge`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7406/XmlConfigMerge-Merge-config-file-settings) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this is visual studio. If you want to test your project on server, then try to test it on local iis instead of the actual server.